# Is it possible to develop a windows application using PHP?

Tags: php, windows

Is it possible to develop a windows application using PHP that should access the information of the OS and other features like writing the content into MS WORD, Excel etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible through: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php

But you won't find much help nor is it efficient to do.

You'd be better of using any of the .NET languages. I'd personally recommend C#.

**However** for your mentioned use-cases there are libraries like [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and PHP also provides drivers for many popular databases.

Comment: I know it is better to go for .NET. But I am familiar with PHP than .NET programming. So just wanted to know.

Comment: You will **still** be better of using .NET!